# How to get the original string of bs4.element.Tag with the outmost tag removed?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following code in `main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1:

import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read(), 'html.parser')
print type(soup.find('a'))
print str(soup.find('a'))
```

The result is the following. But I don't want the outmost tag (i.e.,  and  in this case) be printed. Is there a way to robustly print the original string without the outmost tag?

```
$ ./main.py <<EOF
> <a>x<b>y</b></a>
> EOF
None
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<a>x<b>y</b></a>
```

Comment: `soup.find('a').text` or `soup.find('a').strings` or `soup.find('a').contents`

Comment: @t.m.adam why not post this as an answer? It is the correct one! =)

Answer (score 0):

```
print soup.find('a').get_text()
```

or

```
tag_string = ''
for item in soup.find('a').contents:
    tag_string += str(item)
print tag_string
```